# Auto updates restocked products

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So this is my old code that reads lines from a file and then displays in a stock embed how many lines that file has. But now I want my bot auto updates when a product has been restocked from the websites: Adidas EU, Nike EU and Supreme EU. Is that possible?

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let file1 = fs.readFileSync('spotify.txt').toString();
    let file2 = fs.readFileSync('netflix.txt').toString();
    let file3 = fs.readFileSync('disney+.txt').toString();
    lineCount1 = (file1.match(/\n/g) || '').length;
    lineCount2 = (file2.match(/\n/g) || '').length;
    lineCount3 = (file3.match(/\n/g) || '').length;
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#c59c16")
    .addField(`This guild has the following service(s):`, `**SPOTIFY:**  ${lineCount1} \n **NETFLIX:** ${lineCount2} \n **DISNEY+:** ${lineCount3}`)
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "stock"
  }
```

Comment: You mean, when the spotify.txt file (for example) is updated, the embed is updated too?

Comment: Yeah but now not in a file but in a website

Comment: Yes it is possible. But most likely no one will provide you with a ready-made implementation solution. The question requires trying meta information about adding new products, saving their database, and display. Despite the fact that everything would work correctly regardless of external factors, it will be necessary to take into account many nuances.